# Cómo puedo encontrar xpath de un elemento en el inspector de Internet Explorer 11

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actualmente estoy automatizando a través de Winum, una aplicación en internet explorer, que se llama Bantotal. Necesito buscar una extension o algo parecido en Internet Explorer 11, ya que en otros navegadores no puedo utilizarlos, ya que la aplicación no funciona con el resto de los navegadores.

Comment: winum es este: https://github.com/deb0ch/emacs-winum ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo hacia era:

1. Descargarme el html de la pagina
2. Eliminar los javascript que hacian que al abrirlo con otro navegador no viera el contenido
3. Abrir el html guardado con firefox en una version antigua en la que tengas instalado algo como firePath

No era muy elegante pero era muy eficaz.